# MVC - How i use my model on CSHTML correctly?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I've imported my model into my view, but when i try to use my model from inside my view I get this error

Model imported:

```
 @model mindQI.Models.admModel
```

Model: [Model creation Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7n5c.png) - [Get & Set Itens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoa6n.png)

HTMl Razor example:

```
@Html.GNX_FormTextField("Nome", "nmUsuario", (Model == null ? "" :  Model.NM_USUARIO), "span8 campo", true, false)
```

HTML Razor Error example: 'admModel' does not contain a definition for 'NM_USUARIO' and no extension method 'NM_USUARIO'accepting a first argument of type 'admModel' could be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly referece?)

I really dont know how to proceed.

Comment: You're returning `SPU_MIND_SUI_USUARIOResult` not `admModel` that's why it's throwing this error because they're two different classes

Answer (score 0):

according to your attached model your model name is different.

try

```
@model mindQI.Models.SPU_MIND_SUI_USUARIOResult
```

instead of

```
@model mindQI.Models.admModel
```